# Cubic Curve critical point

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

```
a=-1.89;b=1;
ContourPlot [y^2  ==x^3+a x+b, {x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},GridLines->Automatic]
Clear[a];FindRoot [0==x^3+a x+b,{a,-1.9}]
NSolve[ 0==x^3+a x+b,a]
```

Trying to find constant $a\approx 1.89 $ more accurately for cross-over point. Please help.

[image]

Comment: It is $$y^2=x^3+ax+b$$?

Comment: See for example Cardano's formula for the roots of the cubic. In your case you don't have a crossover point, since there is a tiny gap between the second and third solution. In that region $y^2$ is negative. Try for example $x=0.79$ or $x=0.795$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but I believe you seek $a$ such that the cubic curve
$$y^2=x^3-a x+b \tag{1}$$
has a cross-over point. (I'm changing the sign of $a$ on purpose, and I'm leaving $b$ as a free parameter for generality.) This will happen at the threshold that
$$x^3-ax+b=0 \tag{2}$$
has a double-root.

Such a double-root is necessarily also a root of the derivative: $3x^2-a=0$. This gives $x=\pm\sqrt{a/3}$. Substituting this back into $(2)$ gives
$$0 = \pm\frac{a^{3/2}}{3\sqrt{3}}\mp\frac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt{3}}+b
= \mp\frac{2a^{3/2}}{3\sqrt{3}}+b \quad\to\quad
a^{3/2}=\pm \frac32 b\sqrt{3} \quad\to\quad
a=3\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^{2/3} \tag{3}$$
When $b=1$, this gives $a=\dfrac{3}{2^{2/3}}=1.889881\ldots$ which (with the sign change) corresponds to OP's approximate $-1.89$.

Comment: Main query how Mathematica does not capture it ?

Comment: @Narasimham: Perhaps that's something to ask in the [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com).